# Register Social on Unlimited VPN SDK using Apple Sign in not working

Tags: ios, swift

When user signs in using apple id I am getting authorization. From authorization.credential I can get Identity token and authorizationCode. But the Unlimited VPN sdk needs accessToken to register a new user. You can see my code below.

```
private func registerUsingAppleID(appleIDCredential: ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential) {
        guard let identityTokenData = appleIDCredential.identityToken, let identityTokenString = String(data: identityTokenData, encoding: .utf8) else {
            return
        }
        KSVPNUFacade.default.registerSocial(withLogin: appleIDCredential.email,
                                            serviceType: VPNUSocialServiceTypeApple,
                                            accessToken: identityTokenString,
                                            refreshToken: nil, // For only google
                                            idToken: nil, // For only google
                                            marketingEmails: true,
                                            partnerId: ThirdVpnConfig.getUnlimitedVPNPartnerID()) {
            longAccessToken, data, error in
            // returns error "Request failed. bad gateway"
        }
    }
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Is there any way that I can get access token from apple.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is related to private sdk and looks like it was not an developing issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Social login was not fully implemented from keepsolid's side.